# Erratic key board issue while typing

Tags: keyboard

I'm using an assembled desktop, for last few days I'm noticing my a couple of keys of my keyboard (PS2) is behaving strangely. As for instance, whenever I'm trying to type "O", it's adding a plus sign with it & when I'm pressing the left arrow, its initiating activity of right click menu. Any solution??

Comment: You should try another keyboard so we can find out if it is a software of a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a membrane keyboard or mechanical?

I'm assuming it's the former. And I'm guessing there's somehow -- I don't know if it's possible -- some sort of shorting going on. You could try opening it up (provided you don't mess up any warranty that it may be under), and checking the membrane for any oily residue underneath it. If there is, you could try cleaning it up with a lint-free cloth.

Comment: Let's see.... I'm gonna let you know